Cyclic Voltammetry for a Capacitor - Positive Current, Potential is decreasing?

In the boxed red region, why is the potential decreasing when the current is still positive? To my understanding, when the current is still positive (i.e. not changing direction), the capacitor will accumulate more and more charge.
(Image source: https://www.gamry.com/application-notes/battery-research/testing-electrochemical-capacitors-cyclic-voltammetry-leakage-current/) Doesn't really matter where I got it from though as my experimental data shows the same pattern.

The current is positive ... but the potential is also positive. Note that the curves are being drawn in the "positive" clock circulation. So, yes, when the voltage is diminishing, the current continues charging the cell. These are the curves obtained for a "capacitor" at a low charging rate.

@Antonio51 "when the voltage is diminishing, the current continues charging the cell." If the voltage is diminishing, that means charge must be flowing the opposite way, therefore shouldn't current be negative?

Yes. You are right. I meant the curve in the right "positive" (as shown in the OP figure) part of the cycle. As the current passes under zero, then it is "discharge". The complete cycle is "charge-discharge" with an average voltage. The non-linear behavior of the cell is not taken into account in my simulation.

@Antonio51 Ah okay, so charging cycle is when current is positive. Which must mean that the capacitor stops getting charged when current passes under zero like you said. In the OP figure, the part of the graph in the upper red box has a higher voltage than the part of the graph when current = 0. This is consistent with your (fourth) simulation below. Why is this true? i.e. Why wouldn't the voltage be largest at current = 0?

You must see the voltage and current versus time. As the model of the "system" is an "R-C" ladder (+/- longest ladder), it could be very complicated responding to your late question with the "phase" of "voltage" and "current" at the input. All we could say is that charging occurs when current is positive (whatever voltage is) ...

Remember that the source generator is a triangular voltage with rise and fall time controlled.

@Antonio51 Triangular voltage has a peak. This peak is the highest voltage obtained by the capacitor. By the graph of I vs V, the highest voltage is at the top right in OP figure. This must imply that for everything else after that the current must be negative, as I=C*dV/dt (triangular voltage, and it is falling after the peak). Am I making sense here?

Yes. You are right in a "simple" system. When we use a "transmission" line model system, it is not as simple as this ... See my first figure where the voltage changes very "rapidly" when charging-discharging (vertical line) ... or the third figure where the voltage seems to be a little "higher" until current changes polarity.

I added the circles where you can see that the voltage fall "instantaneously" in the first picture ... and does becoming a little "higher" in the third picture. But note that this occurs in a "linear" circuit.

How would you explain the fourth picture? The voltage is curved a bit. The current is still positive (and therefore charging occurs) yet the voltage seems to be moving from 3 V to something like 2.95 V (i.e. decreasing). I don't really see how this is possible!

Don't know (searching ...). Note that if the frequency is higher, curves are quasi "elliptical" ... Probably, is "bad" model used.

Here are the curves for a linear "capacitor".
The models used are discrete and "transmission" line theory.
The models are "linear", so the curves are "theoretical".


